# Is it possible to enrich the firebaseui EmailAuthProvider registration form to add additional fields as an avatar image in user registration phase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, firebaseui

I am working on an Angular application using **firebaseui** to sing up and sign in on my application using the **Firebase Authentication** service and I have the following doubt.

At the moment I am using only the **EmailAuthProvider** for the user creation (I have to avoid that users can be registered via Google or Facebook).

So I implemented this is my component code handling the registration\authentication features:

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ui: firebaseui.auth.AuthUI;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
                private router:Router,
                private ngZone: NgZone) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        const uiConfig = {
            signInOptions: [
                firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ],
            callbacks: {

                signInSuccessWithAuthResult: this
                    .onLoginSuccessful
                    .bind(this)
            }

        };

        this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.afAuth.auth);

        this.ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);


    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ui.delete();
    }

    onLoginSuccessful(result) {

        console.log("Firebase UI result:", result);

        //this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/work-shift-allocator'));
        this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/gestione-ordini']));

        //this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: itemId }]);

    }
}
```

and this is the related html code:

```
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container" class="auth-container"></div>
```

It works fine and generate this view when I am in "new user registration mode":

[image]

After that I insert the mail related to the new user that I am registering in the system I obtain this page where I can only insert the name and the password for the user related to this e-mail:

[image]

I am asking if there is some way to enrich this form and the logic behing this form to add also the possibility to choose an image that have to be used as avatar and set this avatar into the user on Firebase Authentication service.

Is it possible do it in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own authentication mechanism (**not firebaseUI**) and do as per your requirement. As you want to have some sort of user's profile photo, you need to get the user's profile photo and store it in some kind of storage (*like Firebase Storage*) to store the photo and then attach the photo's URL in the **FirebaseUser** object as *FirebaseUser.photoURL*.

You can find more details here: [Firebase User (JS)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#photourl)